# Sumar fecha con pandas python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas

Con pandas abro un archivo excel el cual contiene una columna con fechas, quiero agregar una nueva celda sumando dos días a la columna fecha...

Ejemplo:

```
Fecha           Fecha Total
2019-07-22      2019-07-24
2019-07-24      2019-07-26
2019-07-20      2019-07-22
2019-07-22      2019-07-24
2019-07-24      2019-07-26
2019-07-18      2019-07-20
2019-07-30      2019-08-01
```

Lo que sucede en el ejemplo es que se le sumas dos días a la columna fecha, también es por eso que en la última fila cambio el mes.

Código:

```
import pandas as pd

Prog = pd.read_excel('Cronograma.xlsx','DETALLE',usecols=['UO','No_Ptas','CANTIDAD','FECHA_DE_ENTREGA_EN_DESTINO'])

filtro_Prog = Prog[ ( Prog.UO.isin(['TLALNEPANTLA', 'TLALNEPANTLA 2']) ) ]

print (filtro_Prog)
```

El tipo de dato de la columna fecha es datetime64[ns].

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente debes crear el [`Timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html) que desees agregar y sumarlo a al columna:

```
import io
import pandas as pd


data = io.StringIO("""\
Fecha
2019-07-22
2019-07-24
2019-07-20
2019-07-22
2019-07-24
2019-07-18
2019-07-30
""")

df = pd.read_csv(data, parse_dates=["Fecha"])
df["Fecha Total"] = df["Fecha"] + pd.Timedelta('2 days')
```

> ```
> >>> df
>        Fecha Fecha Total
> 0 2019-07-22  2019-07-24
> 1 2019-07-24  2019-07-26
> 2 2019-07-20  2019-07-22
> 3 2019-07-22  2019-07-24
> 4 2019-07-24  2019-07-26
> 5 2019-07-18  2019-07-20
> 6 2019-07-30  2019-08-01
> ```

Comment: Gracias, se soluciono el problema (: